# Unable to Add Android Platform - ETIMEDOUT error while downloading Template

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, http-proxy

I am getting ETIMEDOUT error while adding a platform android to an existing cordova project.

I have NPM HTTP and HTTPS proxy configured correct (I installed cordova that way).

But when doing `cordova platform add android` I am getting ETIMEDOUT network timeout error.

Can't proceed and I tried all possible network configurations possible via command-line/IE Options. As per the documentation Cordova binary should use the same network http/https proxy configuration of NPM (Node.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research (Mostly head banging), I found a work-around (but still couldn't fix the network timeout issue). I had to study Cordova implementation for "add platform" to understand this better.

1. Execute `cordova platform add android --verbose` and this will give you the output URL which it tries to connect but fails - For ex - https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=snapshot;h=3.2.0;sf=tgz
2. Download this file (cordova-android-3.2.0-221b10b.tar.gz) using a regular browser which has working internet connection.
3. Open the file in a File Compression Software (for ex - 7zip).
4. This would contain another TAR file (cordova-android-3.2.0-221b10b.tar)
5. Drill into the TAR file to find a folder (cordova-android-3.2.0-221b10b)
6. The command `cordova platform add android` first verifies if these files are present at `%home%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.2.0` folder before it tries to download them.
7. So copy the contents of the folder from Step#5 into the folder `%home%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.2.0` (bin, framework, test, .gitignore, .reviewboardrc, LICENSE...)
8. This process definitely works for Windows 64 bit platform (for 32 bit copy into %USERPROFILE%.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.2.0). For Linux based machines this should be in the home folder for the current user too. So try that.
9. Re-run `cordova platform add android --verbose` and this time it should say

> cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
>
> And should continue to create the Android project for your use.
>
> If you face any other errors, ensure that you have JAVA_HOME set to a JDK folder and JDK Folder\bin is available in the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I resolve it by upgrading from Apache Ant 1.7.0 to Apache Ant 1.8.4

Using Apache Ant 1.7.0, the download will always fail with an "ETIMEDOUT error".